# Http request: Writing binary text file (or image) without headers with filename from content-disposition

Tags: c#, node.js, restsharp

I am adding a file (bytearray) to post data via RestSharp and am sending it to a node.js express server. I want to write the file with the filename from content-disposition. 
My first problem is that when writing the data to the file using fs, it also writes a wrapper with some of the header info:

```
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Hello from c#
-------------------------------28947758029299--
```

The other problem is, that although it writes it to the file, Content-Disposition does not seem to be part of the headers object:

```
[ 'content-type',
  'accept',
  'x-forwarded-port',
  'user-agent',
  'accept-encoding',
  'content-length',
  'host',
  'x-forwarded-for' ]
```

The only solution I can think of is, to temporarily write the file and extract what I need with regex, but I believe that would corrupt image files besides being rather a result of me not properly understanding http requests than a legit solution. I am very new to both C# and node, so it is very patched together from examples I found online:

This is my C# code:

```
public ActionResult Documents(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            if (file == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
            else if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var inputStream = file.InputStream;

                    System.IO.Stream MyStream;
                    int FileLen = file.ContentLength;
                    byte[] input = new byte[FileLen];
                    // Initialize the stream.
                    MyStream = file.InputStream;
                    // Read the file into the byte array.
                    MyStream.Read(input, 0, FileLen);

                    var client = new RestClient("http://128.199.53.59");
                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    request.AddFile("file", input, fileName, "application/octet-stream");
                    RestResponse response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
                    ModelState.Clear();

                    ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
        }              
    }
}
```

And this my relevant node.js:

```js
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    var fileData = [];
    var size = 0;
    request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        size += chunk.length;
        fileData.push(chunk);
    })

    request.on('end', function(){
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(fileData);
        fs.writeFile('logo.txt', buffer, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: After looking at my question typed out, I noticed that I am adding content-disposition indeed only via AddFile and not AddHeader and the wrapper in my textfile being probably the additional parameters in AddFile. I could solve adding content-disposition to the header (and extracting it), but restsharp only lets me remove the content-type from AddFile (otherwise I get a: "The best overloaded method match for 'RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFile(string, string)' has some invalid arguments" error) and it gets written to the file nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `multipart/form-data` parser. For Express, there is [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), [`multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty), and [`formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

If you want to work with the incoming files as streams instead of always saving them to disk, you could use [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)/[`connect-busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) (`busboy` is what powers `multer`) instead.

Comment: Thank so much! I'm using multer now and it does everything, including getting the filename.